# If "0" Then Excel

Tags: excel-formula, nested-if

I am trying to build a formula that does the following:

The main formula for cell S8 is SUM(S4:S7)+S119

but if cell S9 and S119 both equal 0 then I need cell S8 to display $0.00 and ignore the main formula.

Also, if S9 equals 0 but S119 is greater than 0 then compute the main formula

Here are a few formulas I've tried but never the results I need

```
=if(S119=0,SUM(S4:S7)+S119,if(S119>0,SUM(S4:S7)+S119,if(S9=0,"$0.00")))
```

and

```
=if((S119)>0,SUM(S4:S7)+S119,if(AND((S119)=0),(S9=0),"$0.00"))
```

I've also tried ISBLANK instead of AND but that didn't work either.... Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

I was using http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php as my example but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: what if `S9=0` and `S119<0`?

Comment: This is for a budget I created and S119 represents a deduction from savings so it will never be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the main formula as long as S9 and S119 are not *both* zero.  If they are both zero, return 0.

```
=if( and(S9=0,S119=0), 0, sum(S4:S7) )
```

I do not think you want to hard-code the string `"$0.00"` but rather return `0` and format as currency.

Comment: Thanks C8H10N4O2... This worked perfectly. Much appreciated!!... Now that I really look at what you did, I made this more complicated than necessary.. LoL